# When can I use show for feelings?

Tags: word-usage

Can I always use "show" to say what people are feeling or are there exceptions?

For example, can I say:

> He has shown no happiness?

OR

> He has shown that he isn't happy?

Answer (score 1):

We *might* use "show" that way, but on its own and without context, the first sentence is not idiomatic.

We might say, *He has shown he isn't happy **by** [growling/attempting suicide/...]*
but
*He has shown no happiness* is the sort of thing Daleks might say, inspecting their human captive. It doesn't sound quite human.

It is more human to say, *He seems happy/unhappy*, or *He's clearly/evidently happy/unhappy*, or *He has given no indication that he is [un]happy*, or *He has indicated that he is [un]happy*.

Comment: *Has he shown no happiness?* does sound *stilted* to me, but definitely not inhuman - it's just the kind of thing a very "well-spoken" person might say. *He has shown he isn't happy* sounds fine to me too, it's just not expressing *how* (and that might be obvious in context). The more natural suggestions are good! I just think the OP's examples work fine (although you'd generally say *has he* when asking a question, not *he has*)

Comment: @cactustictacs: Note that the OP's question marks are misplaced: his two sentences are statements, not questions. I AM a well-spoken person :-) and I would not say "He has shown no happiness."